# How To add multiplication and division symbol from bitmap in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out how to add these symbols.. 
in my .font bitmap file it says the code is 0xF7 for division
and 0xD7 for the multiplication sign..

Comment: can you share the bitmap and the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, how to use unicode symbols? Just use the unicode escape sequence: `\uxxxx`

```
var my_string = "this is the divide symbol: \u00f7 and " +
                "this is the multiply symbol: \u00d7";
```